# VBA, Regular Expressions: Submatch FirstIndex and Length

Tags: regex, vba, vb6, string-matching

I have a complex grouped regular expression, but in RegExp 5.5 the submatches of a match are returned as strings, there's no exposure to .FirstIndex and .Length. The captured strings are not unique.

Regular expression:

```
([A-Z]+)\s+\[A-Z]?\s+(\d{3})\-(\d{3})\s+([A-Z]?)\-([A-Z]?)
```

Example text:

```
BLAHBLAH A 100-100 A-A    
BLAH 101-101   A-
```

Output:

```
0:BLAHBLAH           0:BLAH
1:100                1:101
2:100                2:101
3:A                  3:A
4:A                  4:
```

At the moment, I loop through submatches, search for a substring, find the position, replace with a space:

```
Dim ub as Long: ub = MatchCollection.Matches(0).Submatches.Count-1
Dim fi() as Long, ln() as Long: Redim fi(ub): Redim ln(ub)

For i = 0 to ub
    fi(i) = Clng(Instr(1, Text, MatchCollection.Matches(0).Submatches(i))
    ln(i) = Clng(Len(MatchCollection.Matches(0).Submatches(i))

    Mid(Text, fi(i), ln(i)) = String$(ln(i), Chr(32))
Next i
```

This obviously won't work for the first example string, because the first occurrence of A is not captured by the regexp.

Any thoughts are highly appreciated!

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Sample inputs and desired outputs would help

Comment: The sample input is in the original post, the desired output is an array submatchvalue - firstindex - length. The only way I could achieve it is to clear the non-captured data from the original string, i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution. In the loop I needed to clear all of the characters prior to the match, so instead of:

```
Mid(Text, fi(i), ln(i)) = String$(ln(i), Chr(32))
```

I needed:

```
Mid(Text, 1, (fi(i)-1)+ ln(i)) = String$(fi(i)-1+ln(i), Chr(32))
```